# How to switch between Android AVD and a real device from Qt Creator

Tags: android, qt-creator

the title basically says it all, I want to be able to specify from Qt Creator, whether to start the application I am developing in an emulator or on a real device.

Right now Qt Creator makes this choice automatically for me and so to deploy to real device I have to shutdown the emulator, so that QtCreator picks the real device. However the catch with this is that the emulator starts up really slow ...

In case this is not possible from Necessitas Qt Creator, is it at least supported by android-sdk tools ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't find any switch or piece of documentation that can make Qt Creator switch between the AVD emulator and a real target.

The only reliable workaround that I've found so far is to close Qt Creator, disconnect/reconnect the USB cable of the target and reopen Qt Creator. In this way the real device is seen as the primary target and is used by default.

Comment: thanks for your confirmation about Qt Creator. The question now stands, whether this is supported by Android SDK at all. I would say yes, but to be honest I haven't investigated further, since there were other higher priority things to do. Hopefully I will find the time to test this over the summer and post the results here.

Comment: I don't think this task belongs to the Android SDK. I suppose that's just a matter of `adb push/install <device>` or similar commands. So this should be a job for Qt Creator. Maybe Qt Creator just asks for a list of connected devices and picks up the first, without asking anything to the user. Eclipse asks something, if I remember correctly...

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but because developing for Android was just a fun side project for me, I have not researched the problem any further since then. Hopefully I will find the time for it over the summer, after I finish my graduation exams.